# SetDataType in ClosedXML was removed

Tags: c#, closedxml

I am trying to set the DataType of a cell to `String` using the method `SetDataType()` in C# in this way:

```
worksheet.Cell(x, y).SetDataType(XLDataType.Text);
```

But `SetDataType()` was removed from ClosedXML since 0.94.0. I am now unsure on how to resolve my problem.

Should I use `SetValue()`? Does it automatically sets the cell's type to the type of the value passed to?

Thank you

**edit** to me, also the type "general" (no specific format) is okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// To set the DataType
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).DataType = XLDataType.Text;

// To set the Value for the cell
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = "Example";
```

##### For context:

This also works for Column(i), Row(i) or Range(i, j)
From what I know most values will be mapped automatically.
If you want to map the values manually you can do something like this:

```
private static XLDataType GetExcelTypeMapping(object value) => value switch {
        int => XLDataType.Number,
        decimal => XLDataType.Number,
        string => XLDataType.Text,
        bool => XLDataType.Boolean,
        System.DateTime => XLDataType.DateTime,
        _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"{value} is not supported."),
};
```

With:

```
foreach (var value in values.FirstOrDefault()) {
    int i = 1;
    worksheet.Column(i) = GetExcelTypeMapping(object value);
    i++;
}
```

in your code. The example is based on IEnumerable<T>.

Comment: In ClosedXML 0.102.1 DataType is read-only property :(

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76610405/3845726